# refreshing url after a function is done, starts the function again

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am kind of confused why this happens but, I have a transaction function which gets called for storing data in the database, but after the process ends, I can see the url is `https://localhost/index.php/main/saveMoneyRequest` but now if I refresh the same page with the same url the same transaction function will be called and another set of data will be stored. I am confused why dis happens, and I am using codeigniter controller function to do the transaction.

When the function ends, i just load views

```
$this->load->view('header',$headerData );   
$this->load->view('borrower_sidebar_view', $sidebarData);
$this->load->view("borrower_summary_view");
$this->load->view("footer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function end with instruction to load the view instead of return value. Then, when you see the page, the URL still the same URL you called previously, so that's the reason why when you hit refresh, it is calling the same function.

I usually end the function with redirect.

That means the web page is fresh, new, just like from blank URL to that URL.

```
function saveMoneyRequest(){
    //your code..
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Your issue here related to [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)